# SMS Sender's Name Shows as labuser in Default SMS App

Tags: android

I installed the following code on my Android 2.2 phone and the sender's name shows as labuser for some messages when it is actually something else :-

```
public class SMSReaderActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final ArrayList<String> smses = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smses);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
            new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body" }, null,
            null, "date desc");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        String msg = cursor.getString(0) + ", " + cursor.getString(1)
                + ", " + cursor.getLong(2) + ", " + cursor.getString(3);
        Log.w("SMS", "Read SMS:" + msg);
        if (cursor.getString(3).indexOf("rbs") >= 0) {
            smses.add(msg);
            Log.w("SMS", "Added");
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

labuser is not an a/c on my development machine and this happens with only matching smses. I cannot figure out the source of this.

Thanks
Himanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving it the READ_CONTACTS permission fixed it. That my app, reading SMS's without appropriate permissions, could screw up the default one was strange.